# Not able to install nodejs 21 in ubuntu wsl

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, node.js

When I try to install nodejs 21 in Ubuntu wsl I get the following error

```
 curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_21.x | sudo -E bash - &&sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Error

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/32.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 201 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 50105 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_21.6.2-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (21.6.2-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_21.6.2-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/node/common.gypi', which is also in package libnode-dev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_21.6.2-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the posted error, the `nodejs` package you are attempting to install contains a file `/usr/include/node/common.gypi` that also belongs to an already installed package `libnode-dev`.  [`dpkg` (Debian's package database)](https://wiki.debian.org/dpkg) is refusing to install the `nodejs` package due to this file conflict.

The first thing that comes to mind to resolve this conflict would be to uninstall `libnode-dev` (`apt-get remove libnode-dev`) and then attempt to install `nodejs` once again (`apt-get install nodejs`).